# How can I convert the code from Mathematica to text and put it in enumerate like this?

Tags: lists, enumitem, wolfram-mathematica

I have a list from Mathematica

```
{{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 
1}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 
1}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 2,2}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}}
```

I would like to convert that list in the form

[image]

I tried it by hand.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
\item $(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1). $ \item $ (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2). $ \item $ (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 
    1). $ \item $ (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 2). $ \item $ (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1). $ \item $ (1, 1, 
    1), (2, 1, 2). $ \item $ (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1). $ \item $ (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 
    2). $ \item $ (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 1). $ \item $ (1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2). $ \item $ (1, 1, 
    2), (1, 2, 1). $ \item $ (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 2). $ \item $ (1, 1, 2), (2, 1, 
    1). $ \item $ (1, 1, 2), (2, 1, 2). $ \item $ (1, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1). $ \item $ (1, 1, 
    2), (2, 2, 2). $ \item $ (1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 1). $ \item $ (1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 
    2). $ \item $ (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 1). $ \item $ (1, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2). $ \item $ (1, 2, 
    1), (2, 1, 1). $ \item $ (1, 2, 1), (2, 1, 2). $ \item $ (1, 2, 1), (2, 2, 
    1). $ \item $ (1, 2, 1), (2, 2, 2). $ \item $ (1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1). $ \item $ (1, 2, 
    2), (1, 1, 2). $ \item $ (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 1). $ \item $ (1, 2, 2), (1, 2, 
    2). $ \item $ (1, 2, 2), (2, 1, 1). $ \item $ (1, 2, 2), (2, 1, 2). $ \item $ (1, 2, 
    2), (2, 2, 1). $ \item $ (1, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2). $ \item $ (2, 1, 1), (1, 1, 
    1). $ \item $ (2, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2). $ \item $ (2, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1). $ \item $ (2, 1, 
    1), (1, 2, 2). $ \item $ (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 1). $ \item $ (2, 1, 1), (2, 1, 
    2). $ \item $ (2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1). $ \item $ (2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2). $ \item $ (2, 1, 
    2), (1, 1, 1). $ \item $ (2, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2). $ \item $ (2, 1, 2), (1, 2, 
    1). $ \item $ (2, 1, 2), (1, 2, 2). $ \item $ (2, 1, 2), (2, 1, 1). $ \item $ (2, 1, 
    2), (2, 1, 2). $ \item $ (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 1). $ \item $ (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 
    2). $ \item $ (2, 2, 1), (1, 1, 1). $ \item $ (2, 2, 1), (1, 1, 2). $ \item $ (2, 2, 
    1), (1, 2, 1). $ \item $ (2, 2, 1), (1, 2, 2). $ \item $ (2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 
    1). $ \item $ (2, 2, 1), (2, 1, 2). $ \item $ (2, 2, 1), (2, 2, 1). $ \item $ (2, 2, 
    1), (2, 2, 2). $ \item $ (2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 1). $ \item $ (2, 2, 2), (1, 1, 
    2). $ \item $ (2, 2, 2), (1, 2, 1). $ \item $ (2, 2, 2), (1, 2, 2). $ \item $ (2, 2, 
    2), (2, 1, 1). $ \item $ (2, 2, 2), (2, 1, 2). $ \item $ (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 1). $ \item $ (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2)$.
\end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

It is difficult for me if the list too long. How can I convert it by text?

Comment: Crossposted to [mathematica.se] https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297097/how-can-i-convert-the-code-from-mathematica-to-text-and-put-it-in-enumerate-like

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution, which makes use of Lua's `string.sub` and `string.gsub` functions. The solution's main requirement is that the long string not have any linebreaks in it.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{luacode} % for 'luacode' env.
\begin{luacode}
s = "{{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 2,2}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}}"
s = s:sub ( 2, -2 )
s = s:gsub ( "%{%{([%d%s%,]*)%}, %{([%d%s%,]*)%}%},?" , "\\item $(%1)$, $(%2)$." )
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*),noitemsep]
\directlua{ tex.sprint ( s ) }
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: After compile with luatext, can I get the text file?

Comment: @JohnPaulPeter - Do you need the text file, or the pdf file? I had been assuming it was the latter. (If it's just the text file, why did you post your query on TeX.SE?)

Comment: I am sorry, I need a text file. I think, text can be solve my question.

Comment: It is very nice with me.I tried it. Thanks.

Comment: I posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297097/how-can-i-convert-the-code-from-mathematica-to-text-and-put-it-in-enumerate-like) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/297104/how-can-i-convert-a-list-containing-three-points-and-its-equation-passing-three?noredirect=1&lq=1), not superuser.se

Answer (score 6):

Here's a way to do it.

#### Create a script

Store your Mathematica output e.g. as list.txt:

```
{{{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 
1}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 
1}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{1, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {1, 2,2}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{1, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 2}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 1}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 2}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 1}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 1, 2}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 1}}, {{2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2}}}
```

A tool made for post-processing is perl, a Practical Extraction and Report Language, like so:

list2latex.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# ~~~ open list ~~~
open F, "list.txt" or die "can't find list.txt\n";
my @l = <F>;

# ~~~ merging into 1 long string ~~~
my $s = "";

foreach(my $i=0; $i <@l; $i++){
    $s .= $l[$i];
}

# ~~~ some clean up ~~~~
$_ = $s;
s/\n//g;            # no more crlf
s/\{\{\{/\{\{/g;    # removing triplets
s/\}\}\}/\}\}/g;

s/\{/\(/g;
s/\}/\)/g;

$s = $_;

  
# ~~~ now, let's create the items ~~~
my @it = split /\)\)/, $s;

foreach(my $i=0; $i<@it; $i++){
    $_ = "\\item \$$it[$i]).\$ \n";
    s/\(\(/\(/;      
    s/\$,\s/\$/;
      
    print $_;
}
```

Of course, it does the same as [Mico's luatex script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708068/245790), but more granulary, so you can follow it by the debugger and modify when needed. Chose a scripting language, you're confident with.

#### Run it

From your command line:

- run
- redirect into `it.txt`

```
>perl list2latex.pl > it.txt
```

#### input it

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
 \begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
    \input{it.txt}
 \end{enumerate} 
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 6):

The easiest point at which to convert the code from Mathematica into LaTeX is when it's still in Mathematica.

After we generate the example list

```
list = Tuples[{1, 2}, {2, 3}]
```

we can use the following Mathematica code to format each row `{{1,1,1},{1,1,1}}` of the list as an `\item $(1,1,1), (1,1,1)$.`:

```
StringJoin[StringTemplate["\\item $(``,``,``), (``,``,``)$. "] 
  @@ Flatten[#] & /@ list]
```

(To explain a bit what's going on: ``` StringTemplate["\\item $(``,``,``), (``,``,``)$. "] ``` tells us the format we want to use for each entry in the list. It expects six inputs, so we `Flatten` the entry to turn it into a list of six numbers rather than a 2 by 3 matrix. We apply (`/@`) the resulting function to every row, and `StringJoin` them together. Later on in this answer, I use `<>`, the inline form of `StringJoin`)

We could take the resulting output and copy-and-paste it into a `.tex` file. (If you do this, be sure to use "Copy as..." and select "Plain Text", or else you'll get something formatted as Mathematica input.) However, we could also ask Mathematica to export it:

```
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "output.tex",
"\\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\\usepackage{enumitem}
\\begin{document}
\\begin{enumerate}[label=\\arabic*)]
" <> (StringTemplate["\\item $(``,``,``), (``,``,``)$. "]
  @@ Flatten[#] & /@ list) <> 
"
\\end{enumerate}
\\end{document}", "Text"]
```

You'll notice that we have to write double backslashes to escape every backslash, and typing that into a Mathematica notebook is a pain. If there's a lot of other stuff you want in the output file, you might want to write the code for it separately. Begin by creating a file named `input.tex` that contains the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
``
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Then, we can just tell Mathematica to take that file and use it as a template for the output:

```
list = Tuples[{1, 2}, {2, 3}];
formattedList = StringJoin[StringTemplate["\\item $(``,``,``), (``,``,``)$. "] 
  @@ Flatten[#] & /@ list];
texTemplate = StringTemplate[Import[NotebookDirectory[] <> "input.tex", "Text"]];
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "output.tex", texTemplate[formattedList], "Text"]
```

(I've been assuming that the Mathematica notebook is saved in a directory where you're happy for `input.tex` and `output.tex` to also live. But of course we can give Mathematica any other file names to use, including ones that don't depend on `NotebookDirectory[]`.)